# Subset sum with `itertools.combinations`

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have a list of integers in python, let's say:

```
weight = [7, 5, 3, 2, 9, 1]
```

How should I use itertools.combinations to find all of the possible subsets of sums that there are with these integers. 
So that I get (an example of desired output with 3 integers - weight = [7, 5, 3]:

```
sums = [ [7], [7+5], [7+3], [7+5+3], [5], [5+3], [3] ]
```

Associated with these weights I have another array called luggages that is a list of lists with the luggage name and its correspondent weight in this format:

```
luggages = [["samsonite", 7], ["Berkin", 5], ["Catelli", 3] .....]
```

I created an array called weight in this manner.

```
weight = numpy.array([c[1] for c in luggages])
```

I could do this for the luggage names need be.
I attempted to use itertools.combinations in this manner (upon suggestion):

```
comb = [combinations(weight, i) for i in range(len(luggages))]
```

My goal:  To print out all the possible subsets of luggage names that I can bring on a trip given the `max_weight = 23` kg of all the combination of each subset that satisfies the condition that the subsets sum equals EXACTLY 23 KG. 
In simpler terms I have to print out a list with the names of the luggages that if its weights were summed would equal the `max_weight = 23` EXACTLY.
Keed in mind: The luggages can be selected only once in each subset but they can appear in as many subsets as possible. Also, The number of items in each subset is irrelevant: it can be 1 luggage, 2, 3... as long as their sum equals exactly 23.

Comment: `[c for i in range(len(luggages)+1) for c in combinations(luggages, i)]` gives you a flattened list of all the possible subsets of luggages. Now you can use a for loop to iterate through those. Inside the loop, you have another loop that adds up the weights of the current subset. If the total weight matches, you iterate again through the current subset and output the names. You don't really need the weight array.

Comment: @NiklasB I think I understand what you mean, this helped a lot! the only question I have is all of the c for i..... for c. I think that I don't really understand how they all work? Any way to explain it to me possibly? Or documentation that I could reference to? Thank you

Comment: It's the same as two nested `for` loops that produce a value `c` that is then added to the back of a list. See my comment to your other question

Comment: @NiklasB. I understand now the nested for loops but the initial `c` is essentially doing/becoming what? And are the `[....]` brackets really needed and what do they do?

Comment: Sorry pal I provided you with a link to the Python documentation that explains list comprehensions, it explains everything. You can also just look for tutorials online or an introductory Python resource. The term you are looking for is "list comprehension". You might want to learn at least the basics of a programming language if you want to program with it ;)

Comment: @NiklasB. every starts from somewhere and practice makes perfect... isn't that the saying?! Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Working on the traveling salesman, are we?  You can do this using everyone's favorite Python feature, list comprehensions:

```
weight = [7, 5, 3, 2, 9, 1]

cmb = []
for x in range(1, len(weight) + 1):
    cmb += itertools.combinations(weight, x)

#cmb now contains all combos, filter out ones over the limit

limit = 23

valid_combos = [i for i in cmb if sum(i) == limit]

print(valid_combos)
```

Comment: Ahh so it is :) I withdraw my comment! I guess our answers are almost identical in ways :)

Comment: I cleaned up the code a little and fixed a bug, hope you don't mind. Also OP wants to print the names, not the weights, but then again we don't need to do all the work for him/her

Comment: Not at all!  Good catch :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Could you please explain what i for i essentially means and does?

Comment: @user3245453: It's not my answer, but it's a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). A similar construct is the [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) which is also used in this answer. Basically they try to bring the mathematical notation for set comprehensions into the programming language, the set `{ 2i | i ∈ R, i > 3}` becomes `[2*i for i in R if i > 3]`

Comment: Niklas' link to the list comprehension docs is the best guide.  In short, the `i for i in cmb` steps through all the elements in list `cmb`.  The `if` statement then filters each element of the list according to the following logical statement, only putting the item in the new list if it matches.  I also like the [python for beginners guide](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/)